# How to handle dropdown under certain condition in angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular I want to make a form that takes four input for bus service these are destination information that is (from location, pickup point, to location, drop point )
the condition is - if you select "New York", then pick up should show be all the available locations for New-York and if from is selected as "Hawai" it shows all the pickup location of Hawai,
the condition is the same for the "to location" and drop point.

I currently having problem-related to understand that how to condition should be applied in a component of angular and how to change any selector value according to the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the onChange event handler to desired dropdown. It should look something like this:

```
<select (change)="onChangeFunction()">...</select>
```

Then in your .ts file you implement the logic behind the onChange event. For example, if selected location is New York, then filter the array containing pickup points and take only ones that are somehow related to New York (this part is specific to your data model).